# scrolling to the top of a webview (Android)

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview loading a big texts after the user has clicked an object.
I like the text to be shown from the top. But if the user scrolled down in the previous text the next is already scrolled and not shown from the top.

I am using `webView.scrollTo(0,0);` in my `onPageFinished` event of the webview.

This works fine in my emulator, but on my phone the text is scrolled in the middle.

when adding a pause with Thread.sleep it also works on my phone. 
What am I doing wrong here ?

My Code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Pause is needed for my physical phone S7. In Emulator there I have no problem.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webView.scrollTo(0,0);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```

Comment: paste some screenshot of the design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this block of code -

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Pause is needed for my physical phone S7. In Emulator there I have no problem.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        view.scrollTo(0,0);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```

Actually, you're so close to the solution. Just the point is you need to set scrollTo in the returned view of onPageFinished method.

Comment: Thank you. I am simply too stupid :-) Thanks for the help. Thread can also be removed now.